# How do I attach a different database to each user in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7

I am building a calendar and appointment website in Django. I want each user to have their own database. I want to know firstly how do I create and save user details and then how do I attach each user to their database??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need a database for each user?

Answer (score -1):

- To attach multiple databases/users, you just need to specify them in the settings.py, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/.
- If you want to create initial data for each users and for each database, you need to use the fixtures, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/